# Calling child method

Tags: c++, abstraction, object-slicing

In my C++ project I have a class called Trap. A Trap is an NPC and an NPC is an Entity. Now I want to loop through all NPC's and do stuff with them. For example, I want a Trap to update. I do that in the following way.

```
for (vector<NPC>::iterator it = Enemies.begin(); it != Enemies.end(); ++it) {
    it->Update();
}
```

But now the Update() call is calling the NPC::Update() method.

I'm confident this is because of the way I used the iterator, but I don't know how to better do this. Use a different kind of iteration? Is there a simple trick for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [Slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) issue.

`Enemies` should be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<NPC>>` (or other smart pointer) or `std::vector<NPC*>`

- [Live example with pointers](https://ideone.com/7WELKr).
- [Live example with unique_ptr](https://ideone.com/xXG6HJ).

Comment: You probably should note that OP should use `std::vector<pointer to NPC>::iterator` or C++11 thing (foreach-loop or `auto` type for it) to handle NPCs.

Comment: I tried this, but it creates TWO new problems...

The first problem is that I'm having trouble iterating through them afterwards. The for loop works just as easily but the following doesn't work. *it->Update();. Secondly, by storing the pointers and not the objects, the NPC's are de-allocated at the end of the stack... I'll have to look into it further.

Comment: @Ozitiho: I have added samples link (using C++11).

Comment: You want run-time polymorphism in c++ through inheritance => you must use either pointers (please use smart_pointers in that case) or references. When you store values in std::vector<BaseClass> stuff that you put in is sliced to a BaseClass instance. I don't understand you problem with "de-allocated" NPCs. Can you post a more complete example ? We are interested in how you create the objects.

Comment: @Jarod42 Wow, way to go out of your way with those examples. Thanks a ton, that solved all of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a pure-virtual base class that defines all the basic functions for your derived class. Then you can implement the actual code in your subclasses and still call the update() method through the base class.

```
class Base
{
    virtual void update() = 0
}

class Implementation: public Base
{
    void update() { /*Do stuff*/ }
}
```

Next create a `vector< unique_ptr<Base> >` (whatever pointer type you need) and fill it with `new( Implementation )` and you can then loop through your vector and do `Base->update()`.

Comment: You may prefer `std::make_unique<Implementation>` over `new Implementation`.

Comment: Yes, good suggestion, that would be preferable. Though I have to add it's a C++14 function so a recent compiler is a necessity.